# Launch a WinForm from a WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WPF application which launches a WPF window. In the window, I want to double click an item in a ListView, which would open a WinForm.

Will there be any side-effects in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No side effects as far as functionality, perhaps a small first-load performance hit, and a slightly bigger assembly if at all.